# How to copy a website element into my Squarespace website? Size Guide

Tags: web, charts, squarespace

I'm trying to copy the size guide code from the website below into my own website - I'm doing something wrong because I'm only able to copy the "Size Guide" but not the actual measurements part. Please help!

https://seen-demo.squarespace.com/shop/p/lloyd-jean-5pfjg

Comment: Do you have a comparison of the size guide and what you expect to see?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.